# Sorting XML using values in python etree

Tags: python, lxml, elementtree

Below is the xml I am trying to sort using etree the value in fullName
to be considered to sort alphabetically

```
<CustomLabels xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <labels>
        <fullName>AnAutoQuote</fullName>
        <value>This is an automatically generated quote.</value>
        <language>en_US</language>
        <protected>false</protected>
        <shortDescription>Automatic Quote</shortDescription>
    </labels>
    <labels>
        <fullName>AManualQuote</fullName>
        <value>This is a manual quote.</value>
        <language>en_US</language>
        <protected>false</protected>
        <shortDescription>Manual Quote</shortDescription>
    </labels>
</CustomLabels>
```

> Code that i tried but it returns the same xml as it got in the input. here xml contains
> the file that was read for input and parser is the xml parser with encoding set to utf-8

```
root = objectify.string(xml, parse)

for r in root.iter("labels"):
    r[:] = sorted(r, key = lambda ch: -(ch.tag=="fullname"))

print(etree.toStrin(root).decode("utf-8))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
root = objectify.fromstring(xml)
root.labels = sorted(root.labels, key=lambda tag: tag.fullName)
```

full code example:

```
from lxml import objectify, etree

xml = '''<CustomLabels xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <labels>
        <fullName>ZZZAManualQuote</fullName>
        <value>This is a manual quote.</value>
        <language>en_US</language>
        <protected>false</protected>
        <shortDescription>Manual Quote</shortDescription>
    </labels>
    <labels>
        <fullName>AnAutoQuote</fullName>
        <value>This is an automatically generated quote.</value>
        <language>en_US</language>
        <protected>false</protected>
        <shortDescription>Automatic Quote</shortDescription>
    </labels>
    <labels>
        <fullName>AManualQuote</fullName>
        <value>This is a manual quote.</value>
        <language>en_US</language>
        <protected>false</protected>
        <shortDescription>Manual Quote</shortDescription>
    </labels>
</CustomLabels>'''

root = objectify.fromstring(xml)
root.labels = sorted(root.labels, key=lambda tag: tag.fullName)

print(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True).decode('utf-8'))
```

**output**

```
<CustomLabels xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <labels>
    <fullName>AManualQuote</fullName>
    <value>This is a manual quote.</value>
    <language>en_US</language>
    <protected>false</protected>
    <shortDescription>Manual Quote</shortDescription>
  </labels>
  <labels>
    <fullName>AnAutoQuote</fullName>
    <value>This is an automatically generated quote.</value>
    <language>en_US</language>
    <protected>false</protected>
    <shortDescription>Automatic Quote</shortDescription>
  </labels>
  <labels>
    <fullName>ZZZAManualQuote</fullName>
    <value>This is a manual quote.</value>
    <language>en_US</language>
    <protected>false</protected>
    <shortDescription>Manual Quote</shortDescription>
  </labels>
</CustomLabels>
```

Comment: this gives an error called 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'labels'